# how to not lose any data in the first activity when you use intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

Okay lets say we have 2 activities such as mainActivity(mA) and secondActivity(sA)
mA is the user interface that takes name,number from the user.
Also there is a textview and a button.
The button leads to the sA.
sA has a calendar that lets you select a day.
You select the day and you come back to mA and the date you selected is written on the text view.
Its okay till here now the problem is, when i come back to mA my previous data that i got from the user is wiped away its empty except my text view that i got the date. How can i save the user data before going to other activity and when i come back they'll stay.

I expect to see my data from the first screen when i come back from the second activity.

**EDIT:**

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), calendarActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            String date = dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("date", date);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

String date = getIntent().getStringExtra("date"); 
tarih.setText(date);
```

Comment: The data in FirstActivity should not disappear unless you are using `finish()` when you navigate away from it.

Comment: i didnt do "finish()" but it disappears when i open a different activity

Comment: "Disappears" is not exactly correct, it should be right there when you press BACK. Maybe you are navigating UP?

Comment: Actually my 2nd activity is just calendar and has a working onSelectedDayChange method which goes back to mainActivity when i select a day so idk really

Comment: Well I don't see the code so I can't tell you where it is going wrong ;)

Comment: To go to the other activity;
`btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),calendarActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}`

Comment: Calendar Activity; `calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                String date = dayOfMonth+"/"+month+"/"+year;



                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("date",date);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }); ` and i did this on mA`String date = getIntent().getStringExtra("date");
        tarih.setText(date);`

Comment: You aren't supposed to be using `startActivity` to navigate backwards. Using two separate Activities for this is already a hack from OS/app perspective, but if you want to go all along with your multi-Activity hack, use `startActivityForResult` to pass results back.

Comment: thanks a lot i finally did it thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `startActivityForResult`.

Read the docs from the official [Android Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Essentially what you would do is to pass data through objects called `Intent`s like so (in Kotlin for instance):

In your first activity:

```
private fun goToSelectDateActivity() {
    val requestCode =324
    val intent = Intent(this, CalendarActivity::class.java)
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
}
```

In your Second activity

```
private fun passSelectedDateToPreviousActivity(selectedDate: Date) {
    val data = Intent()
    data.putExtra("DATE", selectedDate.toString());

    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
    finish()
}
```

Back in your First Activity `override` the method `onActivityResult`

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
     if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return
     when(requestCode) {
         324 -> { yourTextView.text = data.getStringExtra("DATE"); }
         // Other result codes
         else -> {}
     }
}
```

These snippets are very quick and dirty snippets I'd suggest for instance that you have your `requestCode` as a static variable in Java or inside an attribute of the companion object for the Activity in Kotlin.

**The Java equivalent would be**

In your first activity:

```
private void goToSelectDateActivity() {
    int requestCode =324;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CalendarActivity.getClass());
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}
```

In your Second activity

```
private void passSelectedDateToPreviousActivity(Date selectedDate) {
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra("DATE", selectedDate.toString());

    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
    finish();
}
```

Back in your First Activity `override` the method `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;
     switch(requestCode) {
         case 324: 
             yourTextView.setText(data.getStringExtra("DATE"));
             break;
         // Other result codes
         default: break;
     }
}
```

Comment: i feel damn stupid but um what is "val" if u mean validate do u mean like "requestCode =324;" im sorry im a beginner i struggle a bit thank you for your answer btw

Comment: No worries. Kotlin is a bit different from Java, while I write the equivalent in your language you can check out the link that I've provided.

In this case, Kotlin inferes requestCode to be an int; so this would be the exact same in Java as writing: `int requestCode = 324;`

Comment: Check out the Java equivalent!